# What is HIT Archive Data?

Tags: files, binary, archive

When I run `file image.bin` the output I get is: `image.bin: HIT archive data`

I'm not sure exactly what this file/archive type is and Google isn't giving me a solid answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HIT archive data is the format produced by the HIT archiver, a Romanian archiver for DOS written by Bogdan Ureche (hence the “UB” which is [used as the marker in `file`](https://github.com/file/file/blob/093a216e8a18a481ed455849b4a03f64b38ff010/magic/Magdir/archive#L767)). It is available in [`hit.arj` on SAC](https://www.sac.sk/download/pack/hit.arj).